# SQL: What is 'WHERE NOT EXISTS' actually checking?

Tags: sql-server, not-exists

Dong a SQL `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`

What is that clause actually checking? I hope to be inserting the results of col1 from a table into a different table's 'col1', where it isn't already in that table (i.e. col1 is a primary key)

```
INSERT INTO <table> (<col1>)
SELECT DISTINCT N.<col1>
FROM N
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM <table> C
    WHERE
        N.<col1> = C.<col1> 
)
```

it seems to me that the SELECT statement in the NOT EXISTS clause will either return a row (or more than one row), and that NOT EXISTS will look for either 0 rows or more than zero rows.

is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't look for 0 rows.  It looks for any rows.  if any rows exist, then EXISTS evaluates as true.  Likewise, if no rows exist, NOT EXISTS evaluates as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to this, the Not Exist clause can be used for selects or updates in your WHERE clause to **EXCLUDE** records based on what you define in the supporting query.

In your case MERGE is better, but in some cases, like the example below it is also useful:

```
If Not Exists ( Select 1 From dbo.Activities Where ActivityId = 107 AND Activity = 'Facility Updated' )
  Begin
    Insert Into Activities (ActivityId, Activity, CreateDt_GMT, CreatedBy, TimeZoneOffsetMins, ActionTypeId, IsTracked, IgnoreChildren, ProcessExtraInfomation, IgnoreNotChangedData, ApplicationID)
    Values(107, 'Blah', GetDate(), 'SYSTEM', -300, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 )
  End
```

Answer (score 2):

Where not exists is pretty self-explanatory, and will only insert rows where the if the value does not exist in the target table.

However, it is a pretty confusing syntax, and I try to use `MERGE` whenever I need to do any similar operations.